# How do I install nVidia graphics drivers from “X-Swat” ppa?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, ppa

How am I supposed to install nvidia drivers from xorg-edgers? I try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-331
```

and I get

```
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-331
```

The [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) [says there is](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty) nvidia-graphics-drivers-331 for trusty, why wouldn't it install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the launchpad page, `nvidia-graphics-drivers-331` is the name of the source package (you can't install it). this package once built generates the packages you're looking for.

See that [page](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/4074199/+listing-archive-extra) detailing the content of the source package

Basically you need to type the following command instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
```